# Regex experssion replace only double sqaure brackets

Tags: regex

How can i replace square brackets with regex expression in c#?

I'm using this expression but it doesn't work for me.

`var email = Regex.Replace(emailaddress, @"[\[\]']+", "")`

It replaces all the square brackets - @"[[]']+" It doesn't work for me.

This is what i need: To replace only double square brackets from each side

```
[[test]]@gmail.com -> test@gmail.com

[[[[test]]]]]@gmail.com -> [[test]]@gmail.com

[[[test]]]]]@gmail.com -> to [test@gmail.com]]]

[[[[test]]]]@gmail.com -> to [[test@gmail.com]]
```

I need to this check only with a square brackets.

What is the right regex for me?

Comment: The `[..]` construct matches the characters inside the list in a single position. `[ab]` would just match an "a" or a "b", not only "ab". And `[aa]` and `[a]` would match the same single "a". You don't need those `[]` here

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do so:

```
\[{1,2}(\[*)|]{1,2}(]*)
```

---

```
var email = Regex.Replace(emailaddress, @"\[{1,2}(\[*)|]{1,2}(]*)", "$1$2");
```

---

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/2sSsyI/1), and [here](https://rextester.com/DAFO37387).

---

- `\[{1,2}`: Matches `[` between one and two times.
- `(\[*)`: Matches `[` between zero and unlimited times, as much as possible.
- `|`: Or.
- `]{1,2}`: Matches `]` between one and two times.
- `(]*)`: Matches `]` between zero and unlimited times, as much as possible.